# using index match from 2 different list of different length

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of students without class and another list with names and classes. both lists are of different length
I want to compare the names and consequently get the class besides the student name.

INDEX($J$1:$J$146,MATCH(C1,$K$1:$K$146))
column c and column k are of different length

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: For an exact match, you would use `=INDEX($J$1:$J$146,MATCH($C1,$K$1:$K$146,0))` (note the equal sign and the zero). In MS365, you would use `=XLOOKUP($C1,$K$1:$K$146,$J$1:$J$146)` or even better, using the whole `C` column data to spill the result, you would e.g. use `=XLOOKUP($C1000,$K$1:$K$146,$J$1:$J$146)`.